# Audio programming data types

Tags: c++, c, audio, types

I am trying to process audio raw data and am studying code from the web. I don't understand why as soon as one gets to audio programming, one uses `qint64` instead of a simple `int` (I am using Qt) or even more, why to use `char`.

```
 qint64 readData(char *data, qint64 maxlen);
 qint64 writeData(const char *data, qint64 len);
```

`char * data` is a pointer to an array of chars that holds the data. That array holds the samples of the audio. one sample is represented as a value, say unsigned int. Why do we need or use a `char`? I always think of character data but audio data is stored as some numbers like int, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses `qint64` (or generally, a 64-bit data type) because the size of the data in the audio file MAY be bigger than 2GB, which is the limit of a 32-bit signed number (negative lengths tend to be useless for most purposes).

The data is `char` because that is generic and "can be used for anything" - since audio data can be 8, 16, 12, 24 or 32 bits per channel, and the interface doesn't really want to say which until further "down the stack". In other words, it's a stream of bytes, just like when you view a binary file - the bytes may be lumped together in different ways depending on what it actually is supposed to mean. But the interface for this function should "accept anything".